# Ubuntu newbie needs suggestions

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-netbook

I have a netbook (no cd drive) and I currently run windows 7 on but I want to convert to something new.  Here re my specs.

```
Processor :AMD Athlon Neo Processor MV-40 1.60GHz
RAM: 4GB (2.97 useable)
System Type: 32-bit
```

I managed to install 7 on it via bootable usb drive.  So can anyone suggest what will run good?  All I really use my pc for is minor photo editing, browsing, and playing music.

Comment: That CPU has 64-bit support, so you should install a 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay well thats a start.  Im just overwhelmed for what to pick.  I have just played with ubunto a few times and its so clean and nice.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend Lubuntu. It uses a lightweight desktop environment which will ease use of your low end CPU.

Comment: It's not a low end computer. I have similar specs and run Ubuntu.

Comment: Keeping valuable CPU cycles free for photo editing as opposed to running a heavy DE would be more valuable.

Comment: that comment made no sense...

Comment: I am curious would installing the 32bit version make it run any faster?  I was prior running 32bit Windows7.  In all reality I dont even know the difference in 32 and 64bit.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit and it feels a little slow.   Perhaps I am doing something wrong?